# How to access my zend project in browser?

Tags: php, zend-framework, virtualhost

I created a project **student** in **/var/www/**  But I am unable to access it using virtual hots.

```
zf.sh create prohect student
```

I created a file **student** in **/etc/apache2/sites-available** like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName student.dev
        ServerAlias student.dev
        DocumentRoot /var/www/student/public/
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I run this in terminal:

```
sudo a2ensite student
```

I have following line in **/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1    student.dev
```

After I restarted the apache server:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

But when I access http://student.dev/ in browser it gives me following error:

```
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
```

But when I access http://localhost/student/public/index.php directly then it shows me Welcome successfully like this

```
Welcome to the Zend Framework!
This is your project's main page
```

**Edit:**

.htaccess file in public folder

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `<Directory>` configuration in your vhost config.

Your config has to look like that:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName student.dev
    DocumentRoot /var/www/student/public/
    <Directory /var/www/student/public/>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The `AllowOverride` setting tells apache that `.htaccess` files in your public directory may override the general settings.

Comment: I tried this but same error. I have added my **.htaccess** file content in my question above..

Comment: Apache mod_rewrite is installed, configured and active?

Comment: Thanks alot.. I enabled it with `sudo a2enmod rewrite` and it is working now with your above solution. Thanks again....